# resume audio session failed

Tags: ios, session, audio

My simple project does audio recording. I have two buttons, one is “Start Recording” one is “Stop Recording”.

When “**Start** Recording” button is pressed, my code **activates the audio session** and **starts audio recording**:

```
//Activate audio session
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
 [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord];
 NSError *err;
 [audioSession setActive:YES error: &err];
…
 
 recorder = [AVAudioRecorder init: …];
 [recorder delegate] = self;
 [recorder prepareToRecord];
 // Start recording
 [recorder record];
```

When “**Stop** Recording” button is pressed, my code **stops recording** & **deactivates the audio session**:

```
//pause & stop recording
[recorder pause];
[recorder stop];
recorder = nil;

//Deactivate audio session
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:&err];
```

When I run my app, I press “Start recording”, it starts recording fine. Then I press “Stop recording” which works fine too, it stopped recording successfully.

But now if I press “Start recording” button again, the `[audioSession setActive:YES error: &err];` raise the following error:

```
audioSession: "NSOSStatusErrorDomain" "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560557684.)" "[:]"
```

Why? How to get rid of it?

**==Update==**

I also tried to call session `setActive` after 30 seconds delay, it doesn't help.